# Trouble in Integarating Push Notification with Meteor(Android)

Tags: android, meteor, google-cloud-messaging

1. Register Google Cloud Messaging for Android in Google Developers Console
2. We Get API key
3. [meteor-cordova-notifications](https://github.com/richsilv/meteor-cordova-notifications)
4. Update lib/app.js with the SenderID (Project Number) and GCM API Key
5. Start your app with meteor run android-device
6. When Start app on Android App got Crash:

   ReferenceError: Notification Client is not defined

Please Help Me.

```js
/*****************************************************************************/
/* Client App Namespace  */
/*****************************************************************************/
_.extend(App, {
});

App.helpers = {
 showForm: function() {
  return (Meteor.user() && !Meteor.isCordova);
 }
};

_.each(App.helpers, function (helper, key) {
  Handlebars.registerHelper(key, helper);
});

Template.form.events({
 'click [data-action="send-notification"], submit': function (event, template) {
  event.preventDefault();
  Meteor.call('notify', template.$('[data-field="title"]').val(), template.$('[data-field="message"]').val(), function(err, res) {
   if (err) {
    console.log(err);
   } else {
    if (res.userCount) {
     alert('Notification sent.');
    }
   }
  });
 }
});

Accounts.ui.config({
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_ONLY'
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the package itself.

```
meteor add richsilv:cordova-notifications
```